# Позиционирование/растягивание

Tags: html, css

Добрый день.

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. 
Нужно растянуть textarea до конца родительского элемента .box

Используя left и right, textarea прилипает только к левому краю и не растягивается. Размер .field динамичный, следовательно в пикселях размер для textarea не указать.

---

Вот разметка и css: http://jsfiddle.net/R8azp/1/

HTML

```
<div class='field'>
    <div class='move'></div>
    <div class='box'>
        <div class='line'></div>
        <textarea>*textarea*</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.field {
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
}
.move {
    height: 22px;
    background: #ccc;
}
.box {
    min-width: 100%;
    background: #DAE5E8;
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.line {
    width: 40px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background: #555;
}
textarea {
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    resize: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используй:

```
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
```

Очень полезные функции! Советую почаще пользоваться "min-" и "max-".

Если требуется уменьшить что-то на фиксированный размер (в т.ч. и %), то можно использовать calc, доступный в CSS 3:

```
min-width: calc(100% - 40px);
```

Не везде сказано, что между знаками вычисления ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО должен быть пробел!

В данном случае можно поступить чуть проще:

```
width: calc(100% - 40px);
```

Comment: Добавил для textatea mix-width. Но она теперь вылазит за .field
Так как есть left: 40px

Comment: Добавил в ответ функцию calc, уже заодно и проверил на данном коде. Всё работает!

Comment: Я уже пробовал calc ставить. Но в Safari он не работает.